# How to identify when a dynamic button is clicked using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, button, click, dynamic-controls

I am dynamically creating a bunch of buttons

```
<a href="#" id="btnRemove" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-close"></span>REMOVE</a>
```

but how do I identify which one of them was clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you register for the click event the this variable inside this callback will point to the corresponding DOM element that was clicked:

```
$('a').click(function() {
    // this here will represent the anchor that was clicked
    return false;
});
```

Comment: not sure I understood. :/ what element in the button should be made unique and where in the "$('a').click(function() {" do I get to know which button had triggered it?

Comment: @Roger it's the `this` variable inside the click function which will give you the clicked element.

Comment: hmm... could you please give an example? :)

Comment: @Roger, I already gave one. What isn't clear about it? Inside the .click handler simply use the this variable. For example `alert(this.id);` will give you the id of the clicked button.

Comment: oh, that way I should give the buttons a dynamic id too? then how should I link them to the click function, if not by their id?

Comment: @Roger, you don't necessarily need to give your buttons an id. You could use a css classes, HTML5 data-* attributes, ... It all depends on what information you want to fetch in your click handler. For example to fetch some data-* attribute you could use `$(this).data('foo')` where your button would have `data-foo="123"` attribute.